# Use internal representation of autoencoder for anomaly detection

Tags: time-series, autoencoders, anomaly-detection

I've trained an autoencoder to recognize 'positive' time series (the network is a simple fully connected network, no recurrent layers). The problem is that from what my advisor says, I should try to detect anomalies using some statistics on the latent space (like difference between histograms of latent space between good and outlier data), but when I predict time series with outliers I get the same internal representation as with the good data. I believe this is due to the fact that my network can only reproduce the normal data. Do you have any hints? Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is cross posted on [so].

Comment: @Reinstate Monica Where is the related post?